# Reference an array of Google Map markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to reference an array of markers that I created but when I try reference an array element the element receives the message GLOBAL_MARK.0 is null or not an object. I think it might be a scope issue but I'm not sure how to handle it. Here's the code.

```
var GLOBAL_MARK = "[]"
var vcount = 0;

 function load() {

   if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {       
   var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));         
   map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());         
   map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());       
   MyLat = "47.614495"
   MyLng =  "-122.341861"
                                                                            map.setCenter(new GLatLng(MyLat, MyLng), 13); 

    GDownloadUrl("allmarkers.php", function(data) {        
    var xml = GXml.parse(data);          
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");          
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {      
        var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name"); 
        var id = markers[i].getAttribute("id");   
        var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");             
        var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");            
        var point = new GLatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")), parseFloat(markers [i].getAttribute("lng")));             

        var marker = createMarker(point, name, address, type, id);    
        MyAddMarker(marker)
        map.addOverlay(marker);          
     }        
});   
OutTest()    
}    
}      

function MyAddMarker(marker) {
    GLOBAL_MARK[vcount] = marker
    vcount = vcount + 1
}

function OutTest() {
    alert(GLOBAL_MARK[0].getLatLng)
}


function createMarker(point, name, address, type, id, date1, date2) {      
var marker = new GMarker(point, customIcons[type]);    
var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address + "<br><br><input type=\"button\"    value=\"  View Posts  \" onclick=\"view_posts('" + id + "','" + type + "','" + date1 + "','" + date2 + "','no')\">"
 GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {         
 marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
  }); 
   return marker;    
    }
```

Comment: I tried to clean the code up a little think it may be asynchronous issue or scope issue.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of errors in this code.  `GLOBAL_MARK` was definitely declared wrong to be used as an object like you use it in `MyAddMarker()`.  I'll try to fix as many as I can see by eye without actually being able to run the code:

```
GLOBAL_MARK = [];
GDownloadUrl("allmarkers.php", function(data) {        
    var xml = GXml.parse(data);          
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");          
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {      
        var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name"); 
        var id = markers[i].getAttribute("id");   
        var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");             
        var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");            
        var point = new GLatLng(
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")), 
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"))
        );
        var marker = createMarker(point, name, address, type, id);    
        MyAddMarker(marker);
        map.addOverlay(marker);          
     }
// when the code gets here, the data from allmarkers.php is done
});

OutTest();

function MyAddMarker(marker) {
    GLOBAL_MARK[vcount] = marker;
    vcount = vcount + 1;
}

function OutTest() {
    alert(GLOBAL_MARK[0].getLatLng);
}
```

In addition, I don't see a declaration for vcount anywhere.

And, I suspect you're calling `OutTest()` before the anonymous function in `GDownloadUrl` has completed.  That very well may be an asynchronous function that hasn't completed yet when you call `OutTest()`.

Comment: Sorry it is declared outside of the functions as var vcount = 0

Comment: function createMarker(point, name, address, type, id, date1, date2) {      
 var marker = new GMarker(point, customIcons[type]);    
    var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address + "<br><br><input type=\"button\" value=\"  View Posts  \" onclick=\"view_posts('" + id + "','" + type + "','" + date1 + "','" + date2 + "','no')\">"
 //"<br><a href='showtimeline?id=" + id + "'>Show Timeline</a>"; 
 
  
  GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {         
  marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
  
      
 
   }); 
       
    return marker;    
     }

Comment: Matt, you can't put multiline code in comments - it's not readable.  If it's something you need to convey, then put it in your original question (with the Edit button) and add a comment that says you added it to your question.

Comment: I added a new idea on `OutTest()` being called before `GDownloadUrl()` is done.

Comment: It appears to be a timing issue. I put a setTimeout(OutTest(),1000) as a temporary fix (I'm able to pull elements from the array) but I still get that initial error message on the browser status line. If there's a better way to handle this I'm interested. I hate those javascript error messages on the bottom of my browser.

Comment: I added the code below and it seems to resolve things.      function start() { load() setTimeout("OutTest()",1000) } I call it from the html onload.

Comment: @Matt - That's a hack that tries to get lucky with timing.  If you want to call OutTest() after the `GDownloadUrl()` function is finished, then call it from within right after `map.addOverlay(marker);`.  That's when the function is done and the data is actually ready.

Comment: Thanks...that makes sense but that is similar to the way I had it. Except right after would be in the loop. When I first had it I put it right before the end of the function (still a problem)...because its asynchronous the function continues to load and the jscript just continues to run line by line regardless of what progress the load function is in...I hope I'm wrong though because this setTimeout is quite tedious.

Comment: @Matt - Yes, outside the loop, but before the end of the function.

Comment: What I'm looking for is some sort of status number that equals complete like 200 for data OK...but a number for fully downloaded.

Comment: I added one last comment to the code block in my answer.  It says `// when the code gets here, the data from allmarkers.php is done`.  That's all there is.  If you want to know when it's done processing the response, that's when.

Comment: The Google function handles the checking of status codes for you.  You wouldn't get any data if the overall network call wasn't successful.